# mailgun-ruby behind a proxy

Tags: ruby, mailgun

I'm using the mailgun-ruby gem in a sinatra app that is behind a proxy (that requires authentication).

Is there any way to configure the gem to communicate to the mailgun API through this proxy?
Everytime the app outputs
'Mailgun::CommunicationError - Timed out connecting to server'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [looks like `mailgun-ruby` uses `RestClient` behind-the-scenes](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby/blob/master/mailgun.gemspec#L35), which means you should be able to [configure `RestClient` to use a proxy](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#proxy).

It may be as easy as `RestClient.proxy = ENV['http_proxy']`, but you may end up having to monkey-patch `Mailgun::Client`.